# Golang: 3 ways to create a new instance but what's the difference? (Beginner)

Tags: go

I'm new to Golang and from what I've learned so far there are 3 different ways to new up a struct:

```
a := MyStruct {}  // plain by value style. Is that what this is called?
b := new(MyStruct) // using new
c := &MyStruct {} // using a reference
```

[Example](https://play.golang.org/p/AEAn_JVbsv)

I'm not clear as to the actual differences between each of these other then I've found that I have to add a reference `&` symbol when printing the memory address of the object like this `fmt.Printf("%p\n", &a)` when using the "plain" style vs `fmt.Printf("%p\n", b)` for the "new" and "reference" styles. My assumption is that this is because using the "plain" style allocates memory differently but this is just a guess.

It appears that using the "new" and "reference" styles are equivalent options so choosing between those to is a stylistic decision? Is there an idiomatic preference in this language as to which method I should use? Are there other styles that I've not discovered yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Composite literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals)
>
> [Allocation](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Allocation)
>
> [Variable declarations](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variable_declarations)
>
> [Short variable declarations](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations)

```
a := MyStruct {}  
b := new(MyStruct) 
c := &MyStruct {}
```

`a` is a composite literal value. `b` is a pointer to a zero value for the type. `c` is a pointer to a composite literal value. `a` and `c` are very common. `b` is uncommon, in most cases, `c` is used.

Take the [Tour of Go](http://tour.golang.org/welcome/1) for examples.